# How to fix column "sv.last_updated" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by

What I'm trying to achieve is like get the total count of transactions and their total amount for every hour a given day.

I have written a cast query in PostgreSQL. if I execute it gives

> column "sv.last_updated" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

```
select cast('00:00' as time) + g.h * interval '1 hour' as time,
       count(sv.id) as counts,
       sum(sv.amount) as amount
from generate_series(0, 23, 1) g(h) 
left join paymentvirtualization.summery_virtualizer sv 
    on extract(hour from sv.last_updated) = g.h
    and date_trunc('day', sv.last_updated) = '2021-09-28' 
    and sv.guid = '1aecb2ba5c3941fe9cdab0cbf0c64937' 
group by g.h 
order by g.h,sv.last_updated desc limit 1;
```

What is this issue and how can i fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY "time" ORDER BY "time", MAX(sv.last_updated) DESC` (or MIN, or something else).

Comment: You have grouped by hour part of sv.last_updated; ordering by sv.last_updated/min(sv.last_updated)/max(sv.last_updated) will not do anything if you already ordered by its hour part.